# Scala: Is there a way to write a generic function which returns a generic instance with generic arguments?

Tags: scala, reflection

I want to write a generic function which can take a `Class` parameter and an arbitrary list of arguments, say

```
def to[T, A](clazz: Class[_], args: A*): T
```

and it should return an instance of type `T` which accepts constructor arguments of type `A`. I wrote this function

```
def to[T, A](clazz: Class[_], args: A*)(implicit ct: ClassTag[A]): T =
  clazz
    .getConstructor(ct.runtimeClass)
    .newInstance(args.map(a => a.asInstanceOf[Object]): _*)
    .asInstanceOf[T]
```

then I tested it with

```
class Test(params: Set[String])

to[Test, Set[String]](Class.forName(classOf[Test].getName), Set[String]("hello", "test"))
```

but this is throwing

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Test.<init>(scala.collection.immutable.Set)
...
```

Is this even possible to do in Scala?

Comment: If I compile this with `scalac`, it works fine. However, if I run it as a script file with just `scala`, it fails. It looks like `Test` is being wrapped in an implied `Main` class and that counts as one of your constructor arguments. Which way are you running this?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Aha! I was testing this in the scala repl and it was throwing this error. Real puzzler. I wrote this in a scala script and it is working fine. Thanks!

Comment: Great! I was testing it the same way and found myself equally puzzled. I'll write up a real answer in that case.

Comment: Are you sure you really need to do this instead of using a typeclass or any other compile-time mechanism rather than runtiem reflection?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Unfortunately yes, I do need runtime reflection. The reason is context specific–I'm writing some generic platform code that'll support a bunch of different users who can have a variety of different de-serialization classes they will supply at runtime via config files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all of these functions are added to an ordinary Scala file and compiled with `scalac`, then the code runs as intended. However, when you run code in the REPL or using the `scala` script file executor, you get the error shown.

When you run `scala` (either as a REPL or to run a standalone script file), the code you're running gets wrapped in an anonymous `Main` object. We can see this by printing out the actual constructors with

```
clazz.getConstructors().foreach { c =>
  println(c)
}
```

If run in a file compiled the "usual" way with `scalac`, we get

```
public Test(scala.collection.immutable.Set)
```

But if we run it as a script file, we see

```
public Main$$anon$1$Test(Main$$anon$1,scala.collection.immutable.Set)
```

This is because [`getConstructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) adds the outer class as a first argument implicitly. This is a Java Reflection trick, nothing specific to Scala.

> Returns a `Constructor` object that reflects the specified public constructor of the class represented by this Class object. The `parameterTypes` parameter is an array of `Class` objects that identify the constructor's formal parameter types, in declared order. **If this `Class` object represents an inner class declared in a non-static context, the formal parameter types include the explicit enclosing instance as the first parameter.**

(Emphasis mine)

You can *probably* get the current `Main` class by doing some reflection tricks on `this` at the top-level or in the REPL, but it'll be difficult and strange.

---

By the way, your current code only works for one argument.

```
clazz
  .getConstructor(ct.runtimeClass)
  .newInstance(args.map(a => a.asInstanceOf[Object]): _*)
  .asInstanceOf[T]
```

You call `getConstructor` with only a single argument: the type of `A` (one time). If you pass multiple arguments, then `getConstructor` will still look for a single-argument function, but `newInstance` will call it with multiple, causing an `IllegalArgumentException`. If you only need one argument, then I recommend removing the varargs `*` and just taking a single `A`. If not, then you'll probably have to do some more sophisticated [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)-style trickery to get the variable arguments onto the Java side. But that's getting fairly off-topic. If you'd like to get more details on that, I recommend asking about it in another question.